# How do I fill the points of my box plot to be black in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

[image]

I have a plot that looks like this but I would like the points themselves to be filled black. Is there a way I can do this? Here's my code so far:

```
plot <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=Group, y=Genome_Size, fill=Group)) + geom_boxplot()

plot + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1) + labs(x="Group", y = "Genome size (kb)")+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("Free living" = "cornsilk", "Gut" = "cornsilk3","Pathogen" = "cornsilk4"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it myself accidentally. Thought I'd leave this up for anyone having the same issue.

geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1, **fill="black"**)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I adapt your question to use data we all have, so that we can reproduce your problem and test potential solutions.

It fixed for me by moving fill into an aesthetic specific to the box plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg, fill = gear %>% as.character, group = gear)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1) + 
  labs(x="Group", y = "Genome size (kb)")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("3" = "cornsilk", "4" = "cornsilk3", "5" = "cornsilk4"))
```

[image]

Fixed:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg, group = gear)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = gear %>% as.character)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1) + 
  labs(x="Group", y = "Genome size (kb)")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("3" = "cornsilk", "4" = "cornsilk3", "5" = "cornsilk4"))
```

[image]